# Adapter not working with listview

Tags: android, listview, imageview, adapter

I want to display some icons in a listView.
Here it is the Adapter

```
public class IconAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int[] iconList;
    private Context context;
    public IconAdapter(int[] iconList, Context contex) {
        this.iconList = iconList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView mImageView = new ImageView(context);
        mImageView.setBackgroundResource(iconList[position]);
        return mImageView;
    }
}
```

This is how i set the Adapter

```
int[] iconList = new int[]{R.drawable.ic_action_content_new, R.drawable.ic_color_lens_black_48dp};
holder.mListView.setAdapter(new IconAdapter(iconList, context));
```

The problem is that the listView doesn't display anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your getCount() method returns 0...

Change to:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return iconList.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return iconList[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code,

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return iconList.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return iconList[position];
}
```